# Executing a java callout from oracle db

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have uploaded to oracle db (using loadjava) my java class file with a main and a public method in it. How can i call the main or the method in my java class and run it. Imagine the method in the class file adds two numbers or just gives a log comment. I just want to know how to execute a java callout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to wrap your main function inside pl/sql function. Check CREATE FUNCTION syntax in pl/sql docs for more details.

Comment: Thanks.. I was able to do so using the link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chthree.htm